# Changing random number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

```
import random

def guess_number_game():

number = random.randint(1, 101)

points = 0

print('You already have ' + str(points) + ' point(s)')

playing = True

while playing:


    guess = int(input('Guess the number between 1 and 100: '))

    if guess > number:
        print('lower')
    elif guess < number:
        print('Higher')
    else:
        print('You got it, Good job!!')
        playing = False
        points += 1
        play_again = True

    while play_again:

        again = input('Do you want to play again type yes/no: ')

        if again == 'yes':
            playing = True
            play_again = False
        elif again == 'no':
            play_again = False
        else:
            print('please type yes or no')
print('Now you have ' + str(points) + ' point(s)')




guess_number_game()
```

i just started to learn python and i made this simple number guessing game, but
if you try to play again you get the same number.

e.g. the number is 78 and you guessed it but you want to play again so you say you want to play again the number is still 78.

so how do i make it so that the number changes everytime someone plays the game

Comment: You need generate a new random number inside the inner while. while `play_again: ...(number = randbelow(1, 101))`. Tip you can just '''while True"" and then use a break instead of while `play_again: play_again = True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the number to the random generated number in the loop.

Example:

```
import random


def guess_number_game():

   playing = True

   while playing:

      number = random.randint(1, 101)

      points = 0

      print('You already have ' + str(points) + ' point(s)')

      playing = True
      print(number)

      guess = int(input('Guess the number between 1 and 100: '))

      if guess > number:
          print('lower')
      elif guess < number:
          print('Higher')
      else:
          print('You got it, Good job!!')
          playing = False
          points += 1
          play_again = True

      while play_again:

          again = input('Do you want to play again type yes/no: ')

          if again == 'yes':
              playing = True
              play_again = False
          elif again == 'no':
              play_again = False
          else:
              print('please type yes or no')
  print('Now you have ' + str(points) + ' point(s)')




guess_number_game()
```

Answer (score 0):

You define your random number outside of the game, set a new random number when someone decides to play again!

```
import random

def guess_number_game():

    number = randbelow(1, 101)

    points = 0

    print('You already have ' + str(points) + ' point(s)')

    playing = True

    while playing:

        print(number)

        guess = int(input('Guess the number between 1 and 100: '))

        if guess > number:
            print('lower')
        elif guess < number:
            print('Higher')
        else:
            print('You got it, Good job!!')
            playing = False
            points += 1
            play_again = True

        while play_again:

            again = input('Do you want to play again type yes/no: ')

            if again == 'yes':
                playing = True
                play_again = False
                number = randbelow(1, 101)
            elif again == 'no':
                play_again = False
            else:
                print('please type yes or no')
    print('Now you have ' + str(points) + ' point(s)')

guess_number_game()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def guess_number_game():
    points = 0

    print('You already have ' + str(points) + ' point(s)')

    playing = True
    play_again=False

    number = random.randint(1, 101)
    #print(number)

    while playing:

        guess = int(input('Guess the number between 1 and 100: '))

        if guess > number:
            print('lower')
        elif guess < number:
            print('Higher')
        else:
            print('You got it, Good job!!')
            number = random.randint(1, 101)
            points += 1

            again = input('Do you want to play again type yes/no: ')

            if again == 'yes':
                playing = True
            elif again == 'no':
                playing = False

    print('Now you have ' + str(points) + ' point(s)')




guess_number_game()
```